# react native fetch api error with jwt

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jwt, fetch, json-web-token

I am trying to implement Jsonwebtoken in my react native app. I followed the video tutorial on their official site and it worked fine. However, I kept getting errors "UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found" every time I try to make api calls. The api calls all work as expected except I would still get errors like that. I tried the same api calls in postman, they don't give me errors. I found it's possibly because I didn't pass the token back after the api calls?

Here is where I initiate the express-jwt

```
var expressJWT = require('express-jwt')
app.use(expressJWT({secret: 'I like different tastes'}).unless({path:['/api/users/login', '/api/users/register', '/api/users/register/facebook']}))
```

Here is where I log in and create and pass back a jwt to my client side

```
login: function(req,res){
if (req.body.purpose == 'login'){
  User.findOne({'localUser.email': req.body.email,}, function(err, user){
    if (err){
      console.log(err)
      res.status(500).json('error')
    }
    else if(user == null){
      res.status(404).json('not found');
    }
    else{
      if (passwordHash.compareSync(req.body.password, user.localUser.password)){
        var myToken = jwt.sign({username: user.localUser.name}, 'I like different tastes')
        var tmpUser = user.toJSON()
        tmpUser.token = myToken
        res.status(200).json(tmpUser);
      }
      else{
        res.status(401).json('wrong credentials')
      }
    }
  })
}
else{
  res.status(400).json('You are hacked bro')
}
```

And this is an example of the api calls I make after I log in.

```
fetchPost() {
var _this = this
return fetch(uri.network.uri + '/api/posts/fetch', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer '+this.props.activeUser.token,
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      purpose: 'fetchPost',
      latitude: this.state.currentRegion.latitude,
      longitude: this.state.currentRegion.longitude,
      maxSearch: MAX_SEARCH
    })
  })
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.status != 200){
      Alert.alert(
       'Sorry',
       'Unexpected errors!'
      );
      return
    }
    else{
      return response.json();
    }
  })
  .then((responseJson)=>{
    console.log(responseJson)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

}

this.props.activeUser.token is the token I passed back from the second function in server side 
it worked fine and I get the data I want. I also believe I was passing the right token since I tried passing a random token which resulted in incorrect response.

The problem is that I would get UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found.

Comment: What the value of err in console.log?

Comment: console.log(responseJson)? It's the expected values. I can guarantee there is nothing wrong with that